# SQL Server changes is levels of partitioned groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a table that is a list of inventories for different items on different days. The dates are irregular. I want to get a table of changes from the last known value for each SKU group. What is the best way to find this when the dates are irregular?

```
 SKU | Quantity | Date     
 --- | -------- | ----     
123  |  20      | 1/1/17    
123  |  20      | 1/2/17    
123  |  45      | 1/6/17    
123  |  36      | 1/10/17    
555  |  23      | 1/2/17    
555  |  54      | 1/5/17    
555  |  56      | 1/9/17    
555  |  13      | 1/11/17
```

Comment: What would be the result set for the data provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something that works for my need! Wanted to relay this here:

SELECT SKU,
       Date, 
Quantity - LAG(Quantity,1,0) OVER (PARTITION BY SKU ORDER BY SKU, Date) as QTY_CHG
into #tbl
FROM

Select * from #tbl where QTY_CHG != 0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value as-of a particular date, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.date = (select max(t2.date)
                from t2
                where t2.sku = t.sku and t2.date <= @ASOFDATE
               );
```